# How to get the specific option value of a dropdown by passing the option text in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the below line to get the value of a specific option of a dropdown, it is working in IE, but not working in Chrome.

`$("#idDescription option[text='Business']").val();`

Comment: Try this $("#idDescription option[text='Business']").attr('value');

Comment: @Akshay it is not working

Comment: @aleksandar Matic your code is working in IE8, but not in chrome

Comment: see my answer below, I just tested it in Chrome, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$("#idDescription").find("option:contains('Business')").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use :contains pseudoselector.

```
$('#idDescription option:contains("Business")').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#idDescription option").filter(function() { 
    return $(this).text() === 'Business';
})
.first()
.attr("value");
```